# Chain Homotopy for the Barycentric Subdivision of General Chains

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

On page 123 Hatcher defines the chain homotopy map $T$ for general chains by
$T(\sigma) = \sigma_{\#}(T(\Delta^n))$. I am having some trouble understanding this. How is $T(\Delta^n)$ a linear combination of singular simplexes of $\Delta^n$? I thought $\sigma_\#$ was a map from $C_{k}(\Delta^n)$ to $C_{k}(X)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that part Hatcher uses $\Delta^n$ to denote the mapping $1_{\Delta^n} \colon \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$, which is a $n$-chain in the $n$-th module of the singular complex $C_n(X)$.

Your interpretation of $\sigma_\#$ is correct, it's the mapping 
$$\sigma_\# \colon C_k(\Delta^n) \to C_k(X)$$
which sends every singular simplex of $\Delta^n$ (let's say $\tau \colon \Delta^k \to \Delta^n$) in the singular simplex $\sigma_\#(\tau)= \sigma \circ \tau$.

Now to defined the chain homotopy $T \colon C_k(X) \to C_{k+1}(X)$ Hatcher uses the chain homotopy $T \colon C_k(\Delta^n) \to C_{k+1}(\Delta^n)$, that he defined in the previous paragraph.
It defines $T(\sigma)$ (for every $\sigma \colon \Delta^n \to X$) as the image of $\sigma_\# \circ T(\Delta^n)$, where the first $T$ is the chain operator in the complex $C(X)$ while the latter is the chain operator on the complex $C(\Delta^n)$: hence $T(\Delta^n) \in C_{n+1}(\Delta^n)$ and so $\sigma_\#(T(\Delta^n)) \in C_{n+1}(X)$.

Comment: Here is what I don't understand. In what sense is            $(T(\Delta^n))$ an element of the domain of the induced map?

Comment: Do we not need a map from $\Delta^n$ X I to $\Delta^n$?

Comment: @JonathanAronson I've edited the answer: I guess tell me if now it's more clear.

Comment: Ah I see it now.Thanks!

Comment: Now I understand Hatcher's comment about projection in the discussion of T.

Comment: Can you help me out with the part of the proof just before this part: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138245/can-someone-please-explain-the-map-sc-nx-to-c-nx-from-hatchers-at-page