# Can someone please explain the map $S:C_n(X) \to C_n(X)$ from Hatcher's AT page 122?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> *Barycentric Subdivision of General Chains*. Define $S:C_n(X) \to C_n(X)$ by setting $S\sigma = \sigma_\# S\Delta^n$ for a singular $n$-simplex $\sigma: \Delta^n \to X$.

How are we using $S$ in the definition of $S$?

Is this the $S$ from the previous part of the proof?

Is $\Delta^n$ now a map?

---

I know:

Since $\sigma: \Delta^n \to X$ is a $n$-simplex, then $\sigma_\#: C_n(\Delta^n) \to C_n(X)$ is the chain homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

In this formula $\Delta^n$ refers to the identity map on the space $\Delta^n$, considered as a linear $n$-chain on $\Delta^n$.  So $S\Delta^n$ is defined as in part (2) of the proof as another linear $n$-chain on $\Delta^n$ (as the next line of the proof says, it's just a sum of all the simplices in the barycentric subdivision of $\Delta^n$ with appropriate signs).  Then, $\sigma_\# S\Delta^n$ is the $n$-chain on $X$ obtained by applying $\sigma$ to $S\Delta^n$.